# Moving my domain hosting from Bluehost to Heroku

Tags: cloud-hosting, heroku, bluehost

I registered and hosted a new domain with Bluehost because I thought it would be a simple WordPress site. Since then, I have instead created a custom MERN stack application. I understand that Heroku isn't a registrar, so I will have to leave that with Bluehost or move it somewhere else, but I would like to move the hosting of my website to a paid Heroku account, so I can maintain the URL. So far I have nothing but a temporary holding page on Bluehost, so no need to preserve anything. Could someone help me with the process of moving the domain hosting from Bluehost to paid Heroku? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have a holding page, you can't be talking about having a problem moving content, so I can only assume this is about how to set up DNS.

No matter where your domain is registered you need to point it to a host using the `nameservers` settings.  You will find this wherever your domain is registered.  The nameservers tell the internet where your DNS is hosted and it may or may not be where your site and email are hosted.

Wherever DNS is hosted, to point the site to Heroku, you would need to either change the nameservers to point to Heroku (i.e. Heroku now handles DNS) or change the `A Record` to point to the IP address Heroku give you.

For email, a similar process, however this time you change the `MX Record` to point to your email host e.g. an email service or google or office365.

The important thing for your site is the `A Record`.

This is a basic answer, it can be a more complex setup, but this info will get you going.

Comment: Thank you @Steve!  This will get me moving in the right direction and asking the right questions.